# ifndef issue, Warning[Pe014]: extra text after expected end of preprocessing directive

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

```
#ifndef LCD.h
#define LCD.h
extern unsigned char LCDDISPLAY[][64];
void write(int x_start, int y_start, char text[]);
#endif // #ifndef LCD.h
```

Error message:

> Warning[Pe014]: extra text after expected end of preprocessing directive

Comment: Also, consider picking a [meaningful username](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). One advantage to this is others can use [at-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) and you'll get a notification that someone has addressed you in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You don't normally use dots in identifiers.

Comment: In fact you *can't*.  `LDC.h` isn't an identifier; it's an identifier followed by a `.` followed by another identifier.

Comment: Yes, @KeithThompson, it was my way of saying you can't ;)

Comment: Yes, and the comment was my way of saying that you didn't say it clearly enough.  You implied that you can use dots in identifiers in some cases, and someone looking for an answer to the question might not know better.

Comment: @KeithThompson, strictly speaking, you're right. Though by "my way" I meant "slightly sarcastic way". Not to mock the OP, just to liven up the place ;-)

Comment: @KeithThompson, and yes, I upvoted your comment for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

The defined name must be a regular identifier, containing only a-z, underscore and 0-9 characters but not beginning with a number. In

```
#define LCD.h
```

`LCD` is considered to be the "identifier", and the rest of it is junk text (hence the extra text warning).

Answer (score 2):

Change the first lines to

```
#ifndef LCD_H
#define LCD_H
```

Since you cannot use `.` in `#if..` macros you'll replace it with an `_` (of course, this is only one way)

Comment: This is slightly inaccurate. Of course, you can use `.` in macros. `ifndef` "expects" an identifier (a potential macro name) afterwards (and then a line-break). And identifiers/macro names cannot contain `.`.